# Slide Up an image using EventMotion in Android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I am trying to slide up a layout in android using touch listener. I am expecting the MOTION_UP should be intercepted when the user touches the screen and drags the finger up the screen. And MOTION_DOWN the other way. But when i debug, both Up and Down are called.

I am trying to slide the layout up when I drag up using animation. I don't understand what i am doing wrong. Did anyone had this situation before? Any hints are helpful, Thank you.

This is my code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener,
        OnDragListener {

    // Animation
    private Animation animSlideUp;
    private ImageView img;
    private Rect rect;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.interstitialImg);
        img.setOnDragListener(this);
        img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    System.out.println("up");

                    rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v
                            .getBottom());
                    v.getHitRect(rect);
                    if (rect.contains(Math.round(v.getX() + event.getX()),
                            Math.round(v.getY() + event.getY()))) {
                        System.out.println("inside");
                        // Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        // getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
                        // img.startAnimation(slide_up);
                    } else {
                        // outside
                        System.out.println("outside");
                    }
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    System.out.println("down");
                    // Construct a rect of the view's bounds
                    rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v
                            .getBottom());
                    return true;
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    // if (!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(),
                    // v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())) {
                    // // User moved outside bounds
                    // System.out.println("moved outside bounds " + rect);
                    // }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // check for zoom in animation
        if (animation == animSlideUp) {
            System.out.println("animation: " + animation);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_up);
            finish();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
            System.out.println("action drop");
            View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            RelativeLayout to = (RelativeLayout) v;
            to.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_up);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am expecting the MOTION_UP should be intercepted when the user touches the screen and drags the finger up the screen.

Uh, no.

Docs to the rescue:

> **public static final int ACTION_DOWN** 
>   A pressed gesture has started, the motion contains the initial starting location.

Think of ACTION_DOWN as the very start of user interaction. `DOWN` DOES NOT INDICATE DIRECTION. In a crude sense, it tells you that the user has put his/her finger(s) down on the screen.

Similarly:

> **public static final int ACTION_UP** 
>   A pressed gesture has finished, the motion contains the final release location as well as any intermediate points since the last down or move event.

Again, `UP` is not what you're assuming it to be. It means that the user has lifted his/her finger(s) off the screen.

Let's look at your code now:

```
rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v
                        .getBottom());
v.getHitRect(rect);
if (rect.contains(Math.round(v.getX() + event.getX()),
                        Math.round(v.getY() + event.getY()))) {
    System.out.println("inside");
    // Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
    // getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
    // img.startAnimation(slide_up);
} else {
    // outside
    System.out.println("outside");
}
```

First, `getHitRect(Rect)` fills the `rect` you supply as an argument. So, initializing it with `v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom()` is not required.

Second, since you are setting an `OnTouchListener` on `img`, why do you need to check if `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` are inside the view's bounds? In fact, you don't. Because, `onTouch(...)` *will not be triggered if the user touches outside*.

Third, you may not need to implement an `OnTouchListener` to do what you want.. or at least, not in the way you currently are. For example, if all you are looking for is if the user has `flinged` the view UP or DOWN, you can rely on a `SimpleOnGestureListener`. The accepted answer on this question will show you how to use it: [Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures).

So what exactly are these ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP events used for? Well, you work with them when you need finer control: like reacting to user input *immediately*. For example, you cannot even afford the basic functionality of moving a view around the screen using a  `SimpleOnGestureListener`.